# Scrape webpage element with text or href criteria simultaneously

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In the code below I can either write a function to pass to `soup.find_all` to search for regular expressions in the text or search with `href` keyword inside the reference.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


# s is an example string. Scraping a webpage in reality.
s = """<tr>
            <td><a href="/-/media/markets-ops/rpm/rpm-auction-info/2023-2024/2023-2024-base-residual-auction-report.ashx" target="_blank">Report&nbsp;<i class="new-pdf">PDF</i></a> | <a href="/-/media/markets-ops/rpm/rpm-auction-info/2023-2024/2023-2024-base-residual-auction-results.ashx" target="_blank">Results&nbsp;<i class="new-xls">XLS</i></a>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">6.21.2022</td>
        </tr>
        
    <tr>
            <td><strong>3rd Incremental Auction</strong><br>
            <a href="/-/media/markets-ops/rpm/rpm-auction-info/2021-2022/2021-2022-third-incremental-auction-report.ashx" target="_blank">Report&nbsp;<i class="new-pdf">PDF</i></a>&nbsp;| <a href="/-/media/markets-ops/rpm/rpm-auction-info/2021-2022/2021-2022-third-incremental-auction-results.ashx" target="_blank">Results&nbsp;<i class="new-xls">XLS</i></a><br>
            <a href="/-/media/markets-ops/rpm/rpm-auction-info/2021-2022/2021-2022-third-incremental-auction-pre-auction-credit-calculator.ashx" target="_blank">Capacity Performance Pre-Auction Credit Calculator&nbsp;<i class="new-xls">XLS</i></a><br>
            <a href="/-/media/markets-ops/rpm/rpm-auction-info/2021-2022/2021-2022-third-ia-planning-parameters.ashx" target="_blank">Planning Parameters&nbsp;<i class="new-xls">XLS</i></a></td>
            <td style="text-align: right;"><br>
            3.5.2021<br>
            2.1.2021<br>
            <br>
            3.9.2021</td>
        </tr>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')

# 1) href search
gr = 'base-residual'
soup.find_all(href = re.compile(gr, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL))

# 2) function search, this doesn't look inside the href  

def find_auction_results(tag):

    return tag.name == "tr" and bool(re.search("3rd Incremental Auction", tag.text, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL))

soup.find_all(find_auction_results)
```

How can I do both in the same call, or in two different calls but with a single joined output? With the latter I can simply use `list.extend()` but what if there is an overlap? How would I in that case return a non-overlapping entity to process further? Can I search for a regular expression both in the text and in href simultaneously?

Expect: unique non-overlapping soup list.
Get: two different calls.

Comment: which tag do you want? the `a` tag? or the `tr` tag wrapping the `a` tag?

Comment: you can do what ever you want in the `find_auction_results`...you don't have to return in one statement - you can check everything [tag name, href, text, parents, children, etc], and set the value of a return variable and then return that

Comment: Also, try `soup.select('*[href*="base-residual"], tr:-soup-contains("3rd Incremental Auction")')` [ you might need to use [`html5lib`](https://pypi.org/project/html5lib/) instead of `html.parser` though]. Is that the kind of results you're looking for?

Comment: @Driftr95 How to get a unique list (the type that `find_all` returns) that would have all the  `tr` elements either have subpart with a function search of the element text OR hase href containing certain substring?

Comment: [`select` can do most of that; afaik it can't handle regex (beyond *starts-with*, *ends-with* and *contains*), and I'm pretty sure it's case sensitive.] I feel like you're not realizing just how much you can do inside `find_auction_results` (although ofc, the more you do, the slower it will get) - please see my answer. I'm curious about which approach you might find useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, if you have [`html5lib`](https://pypi.org/project/html5lib/) parser, you can use [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

```py
auction_results = soup.select('tr:-soup-contains("3rd Incremental Auction"), tr:has(*[href*="base-residual"])')
```

or, if you want to parametrize it a bit

```py
inText, inAttr = "3rd Incremental Auction", "base-residual"
tag, attr = "tr", "href"
selector = f'{tag}:-soup-contains("{inText}"), tr:has(*[{attr}*="{inAttr}"])'
auction_results = soup.select(selector)
```

---

It's pretty much the same as

```py
auction_results = soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == tag and ((
    t.find(lambda c: c.get(attr) and inAttr in c.get(attr)) is not None
) or (t.text and inText in t.text)))
```

It's case-sensitive, but with `find_all`, you can also use `re.search(inText, t.text, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)` instead of `inText in t.text` (and similarly replace `inAttr in c.get(attr)` as well).

---

It's not a problem in this particular case, but if `tag` is something commonly nested like `div` [or even sometimes with `tr` in nested tables], parent tags with the same name will also be included in `auction_results`; but you can filter those out with

```py
auction_results = [
    ar for ar in auction_results if not 
    [c for c in auction_results if ar in c.parents]
]
```

---

---

Or, you can also put it all in a function so that parent tags also get filtered out in one call with something like `soup.find_all(lambda t: find_results(t, inText , inAttr))`

```py
def checkPat(pat, main): # for convenience
    return True if re.search(pat, main, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL) else False

def find_results(tag, textPat, attrPat, tagName='tr', attrName='href'):     
    if tag.name != tagName: return False  
       
    hasText = checkPat(textPat, tag.text) if tag.text else False
    hasAttr = tag.find(lambda t: t.get(attrName) and checkPat(
        attrPat, t.get(attrName))) is not None
    
    if hasText or hasAttr:
        if not tag.find(lambda t: find_results(t,textPat,attrPat,tagName,attrName)): 
            return True
    return False
```

---

Or, if you'll always be using the same parameters and want to be able to just use something like `soup.find_all(find_auction_results)` without `lambda`

```py
# def checkPat... # as before

def find_auction_results(tag):  
    textPat = "3rd Incremental Auction" 
    attrPat = "base-residual"
    tagName, attrName = "tr", "href"
    
    if tag.name != tagName: return False # has to be tr
       
    hasText = checkPat(textPat, tag.text) if tag.text else False
    hasAttr = tag.find(lambda t: t.get(attrName) and checkPat(
        attrPat, t.get(attrName))) is not None
    
    if hasText or hasAttr:
        # if nested like [ tr -> tr -> a ] , will only allow inner tr
        if not tag.find(find_auction_results): return True
    return False
```

Comment: Having all in a function is great. Speed is not important in my code. It has to run once in a month.

Comment: @randomrandom123 thanks for letting me know [I actually didn't know before that you could just call `find(method_name)`. I haven't yet needed to target anything I couldn't figure out a selector or `lambda....` expression for, but this opens up so many possibilities!]